# Controlling Excel addins (e.g. solver) from COM in C#

Tags: c#, excel, com, solver, vba

I would like to know if it is possible to control Excel's addins, specifically solver from C#.

I have gotten this far:

```
var Solver = Excel.Application.AddIns["Solver Add-in"];
```

I can't find any documentation, but when exploring this COM Object in Microsoft's Visual Studio debugger, it shows a name parameter referring to "SOLVER.XLAM", which I presume means I'm on the right track. There don't appear to be any useful methods in this COM Object though.

Does anyone know how to rewrite this VBA code to work in C# for example?

```
SolverOk SetCell:="$G$39", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:= _
    "$H$5:$H$17,$H$19:$H$22,$H$24:$H$32,$H$34:$H$37", Engine:=1, EngineDesc:= _
    "GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve
```

Comment: The easiest way to program Excel in C# is to use VSTO - Visual Studio Tools for Office which comes with Visual Studio. see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/hh133430.aspx

Comment: Thanks. This is a good resource, for some reason a lot of those pages don't show up on google

Answer (score 3):

You could write a wrapper for the SolverOK function in VBA, as a subroutine in your workbook's macro code. Next you would call that from C#.

Here's an example of barebones VBA:

```
Sub SolverOkWrapper(setCell As String, maxMinVal As Double, valueOf As Double, byChange As String, engine As Integer, engineDesc As String)

    SolverOk setCell, maxMinVal, valueOf, byChange, engine, engineDesc
    SolverSolve True

End Sub
```

Then in C# you can do something like this:

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application appExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        appExcel.Visible = true;
        //If you go with this route, use appExcel.AddIns["Solver Add-In"].Installed() to check if solver is installed before continue

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\yourPathHere\\yourWorkbookWithWrapperMacroHere.xlsm",
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        appExcel.Run("SolverOkWrapper", "$A1$1", 1, 0, "$B$1", 1, "GRG Nonlinear");
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, and is a pretty good workaround, but I still wonder if there is a way to access Solver directly.